How can I get all results concatenated from a column group by UID?
I need to build a SQL query, for MySQL 5.7, if it is possible, to "GROUP BY" uid and title and concat the permissions column and separate with a |? I am saying GROUP BY but I do not know if that is the right term here.
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
| uid  | title  | permissions                                    |
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
| 1438 | Delete | /_permission_set.php|/process.php|/command.php |
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
| 1438 | Remove | /_permission_set.php|/process.php|/command.php |
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+

I have tried the following SQL (as you can see in this DBFiddle) but it did not work
SELECT uid, CONCAT('|', permissions)
FROM some_table
WHERE uid=1438
GROUP BY uid, permissions;


GROUP BY needs in aggregate function which is GROUP_CONCAT(). Also you'd group not by permission but by title.

Aside: MyISAM has been deprecated for ~ a decade now. 5.7 went EOL last year!

@Vérace there are a lot of old systems which still relies on MyISAM (lock table style)

Lots of people relied on slavery, doesn't mean it (or people) should be kept! :-)

SELECT uid, title, GROUP_CONCAT(permissions SEPARATOR '|')
FROM some_table
WHERE uid=1438
GROUP BY uid, title;




uid
title
GROUP_CONCAT(permissions SEPARATOR '|')




1438
Delete
/_permission_set.php|/process.php|/command.php


1438
Remove
/_permission_set.php|/process.php|/command.php



fiddle
